# HarfBuzz language_from_string Python introspection method doesn't accept str

Tags: python, gobject-introspection, harfbuzz

I'm just getting started with HarfBuzz, and have switched to using the [GObject Introspection interface](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/blob/master/README.python.md) to explore its API.  Everything has been easy so far, but I'm a bit confused with [`language_from_string`](https://harfbuzz.github.io/harfbuzz-hb-common.html#hb-language-from-string), which has the following docstring:

> `language_from_string(str:list) -> HarfBuzz.language_t`

i.e. in IPython, I do:

```
from gi.repository import HarfBuzz

?HarfBuzz.language_from_string
```

in vanilla Python, you can replace the last line with: `print(HarfBuzz.language_from_string.__doc__)` (or similar)

if I call this method with a string, e.g:

```
HarfBuzz.language_from_string('en')
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Item 0: Must be number, not str
```

back, while if I convert to a list of code points first:

```
en = HarfBuzz.language_from_string(list(map(ord, 'en')))
```

the error goes away, and I get something useful back.  e.g. I can do:

```
HarfBuzz.language_to_string(en)
```

and I get the expected `en` back, in a string.

HarfBuzz [Issue #91](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/issues/91) is about this method, but doesn't seem to be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call it like `HarfBuzz.language_from_string(b'en')` (string but prefixed with b) in python3 as strings are not just sequence of bytes anymore in py3 unlike py2.

Do you know any gi API that gets an actual python representation of string in python3? If so let me know otherwise this is expected from HarfBuzz side.

Comment: thanks for that; somewhat obvious, not sure why it didn't occur to me to try that!  I don't know gi very well, but will have a look and will post if I see anything helpful